# How to get photos off device?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, screen, remote-control

My samsung galaxy s4 screen and touch no longer work and I am trying to move my photos to my mac. The screen is locked and the mac is not authorized to connect the phone. I've tried to use a mouse to control the phone, it didn't work. I do not have a samsung account so I cannot unlock the screen that way. I know the problem could probably be solved by rooting but because I need my warranty this is not an option. I have onedrive(skydrive) installed, maybe it is possible to remotely activate photo backups?

**My question:**
How can I get my photos off the device? or how can I unlock the screen so I can get the photos off the device?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could be very useful is adb commands, but that only works if you have USB debugging enabled under developer options. If you happen to be in that situation, you can connect your phone to your computer and you can easily unlock your phone that way.

Otherwise, using a mouse is the only other option I can think of. The easiest solution is adb, however, if you can find a way to make it work.

Comment: This is a good idea, I have actually tried it but as earlier mentioned I have to authorize my computer from my broken phone to use adb.(Unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: @user73759 No, if you have USB debugging enabled you can plug it in and run commands from the get-go. If you don't, then you wont be able to use this method.

Comment: What is the get-go?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Bluetooth on and paired with a device? If you were signed in to a google account on it, the photos should be `Auto Backed Up`. You said you tried using a mouse, you could try using a keyboard with a OTG cable (Use the ←↑↓→ keys to select items and then press enter to click on it). If you had android device manager enabled then there is ways to change the password (That probably wont help though, unless you had the keyboard working with the OTG cable). You could try unlocking it using the bootloader (I don't know much about this so i cant give you any info)